# python: restarting a loop

Tags: python, loops

i have:

```
for i in range(2,n):
    if(something):
       do something
    else:
       do something else
       i = 2 **restart the loop
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to restart that loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You may want to consider using a different type of loop where that logic is applicable, because it is the most obvious answer.

perhaps a:

```
i=2
while i < n:
    if something:
       do something
       i += 1
    else: 
       do something else  
       i = 2 #restart the loop
```

Comment: Just a reminder: with a while loop, make sure you have a termination condition that can always be satisfied.

Comment: I reckon this will terminate when i>=n

Comment: But there's nothing preventing i from continuing to reset to 2 indefinitely, depending on the "if something" test.

Comment: So it depends more on the if-test than the loop invariant? Is there another solution that avoids this while staying simple(because simplicity is key)? Won't there always be the same risk in any loop with the potential to restart?

Answer (score 20):

Changing the index variable `i` from within the loop is unlikely to do what you expect. You may need to use a `while` loop instead, and control the incrementing of the loop variable yourself. Each time around the `for` loop, `i` is reassigned with the next value from `range()`. So something like:

```
i = 2
while i < n:
    if(something):
        do something
    else:
        do something else
        i = 2 # restart the loop
        continue
    i += 1
```

In my example, the [`continue`](http://python.org/doc/2.5/ref/continue.html) statement jumps back up to the top of the loop, skipping the `i += 1` statement for that iteration. Otherwise, `i` is incremented as you would expect (same as the `for` loop).

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using a generator's [`send()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.send):

```
def restartable(seq):
    while True:
        for item in seq:
            restart = yield item
            if restart:
                break
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Example Usage:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
total = 0
r = restartable(x)
for item in r:
    if item == 5 and total < 100:
        total += r.send(True) 
    else:
        total += item
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post an alternative which might be more genearally usable. Most of the existing solutions use a loop index to avoid this. But you don't have to use an index - the key here is that unlike a for loop, where the loop variable is hidden, the loop variable is exposed.

You can do very similar things with iterators/generators:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
xi = iter(x)
ival = xi.next()
while not exit_condition(ival):
    # Do some ival stuff
    if ival == 4:
        xi = iter(x)
    ival = xi.next()
```

It's not as clean, but still retains the ability to write to the loop iterator itself.

*Usually*, when you think you want to do this, your algorithm is wrong, and you should rewrite it more cleanly. Probably what you really want to do is use a generator/coroutine instead. But it is at least possible.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
ls = []
count = False

while ls != a :
    print(a[count])
    if a[count] != a[-1] :
        count = count + 1
    else :
        count = False
```

Restart while loop.