# Converting string values to float and removing strings from list

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like this

```
lst = ['a','b','43.23','c','9','22']
```

I would like to remove the elements that cannot be represented as floats and hence I am doing the following (Attempt 1):

```
for i,j in enumerate(lst):
    try:
        lst[i]=float(j)
    except:
        lst.remove(j)
```

Which leaves the list looking like this

```
lst = ['b', 43.23, '9', 22.0]
```

whereas what I need is this

```
lst = [43.23, 9.0 , 22.0]
```

And so I'm doing the following:

```
for i,j in enumerate(lst):
    try:
        lst[i]=float(j)
    except:
        pass
lst = [i for i in lst if type(i) != str]
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this.?

EDIT: Changed the name of example list from 'list' to 'lst' based on the recommendations below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't manipulate the list you're iterating through (and you shouldn't call it `list` neither, since you would shadow the built-in `list`), since that messes up with the indexes.

The reason why `'b'` shows up in your output is that during the first iteration, `'a'` is not a float, so it gets removed. Thus your list becomes:

```
['b','43.23','c','9','22']
```

and `b` becomes `list[0]`. However, the next iteration calls `list[1]` skipping thus `'b'`.

To avoid such an issue, you can define a second list and append the suitable values to that:

```
l1 = ['a','b','43.23','c','9','22']
l2 = []

for item in l1:
    try:
        l2.append(float(item))
    except ValueError:  # bare exception statements are bad practice too!
        pass
```

Comment: Got that, but I have a dictionary full of many lists like the one above and creating another dictionary full of lists..may not look good..? I am okay with manipulating the original lists though.

Comment: Updated the answer so that it explains why you shouldn't manipulate the list while looping through that @AshutoshSharma For the dictionary, you could just assign `l2` to the old key

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929881/2549021):

```
def isfloat(value):
  try:
    float(value)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    return False
```

And, then use it in a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = ['a','b','43.23','c','9','22']
>>> [float(x) for x in l if isfloat(x)]
# [43.23, 9.0, 22.0]
```

Comment: Roughly the same as what I am doing. Would like to know what am I doing wrong in the first attempt.?

Comment: In the first attempt, you are removing the items from list while changing the `ith` value in the list and that's why there is discrepancy.

Comment: Yes, the tuple values in the next() iterator for enumerate() gets the updated 'j' values whereas the index 'i' remains same and reads the 'j' from the updated list. Any ideas what can be done to make it work.?

Comment: I wouldn't chose to go over playing with the index in the list when I have a better method which is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

First you shouldn't name your variable `list` it will shadow the built-in `list` *function/class*. You can use a simple function to do this:

```
>>> lst = ['a','b','43.23','c','9','22']
>>> def is_float(el):
...     try:
...         return float(el)
...     except ValueError:
...         pass
... 
>>> [i for i in lst if is_float(i)]
['43.23', '9', '22']
>>> [float(i) for i in lst if is_float(i)] # to return a list of floating point number
[43.23, 9.0, 22.0]
```

The problem with your code is that you are trying to modify your `list` while iterating. Instead you can make a copy of your list then use the element index to remove their value.

```
lst = ['a','b','43.23','c','9','22']
lst_copy = lst.copy()
for el in lst:
    try:
        float(val)
    except ValueError:
        lst_copy.remove(el)
```

Of course this is less efficient than the solution using the list comprehension with a predicate because you first need to make a copy of your original list.

Comment: Roughly the same as what I am doing (i haven't used a function of course). Would like to know what am I doing wrong in the first attempt.?

Comment: @AshutoshSharma I've updated my answer. I hope it  makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Would be better in considering iterators to efficiently use system memory. Here is my take to the solution.

```
def func(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
   except ValueError:
        pass

filter(lambda x: x, map(func, li))
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing idea from this post : [python: restarting a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492860/python-restarting-a-loop), the first attempt can be fixed with a simple while loop

```
lst = ['a','b','43.23','c','9','22']
temp = 0
while temp<len(lst):
      try:
         lst[temp] = float(lst[temp])
         temp+=1
      except ValueError:
         lst.remove(lst[temp])
         temp = 0
```

which leaves me with the desired result (by resetting the loop iterator)

```
lst = [43.23, 9.0 , 22.0]
```