# getting a for loop to restart if a condition is satisfied

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a way to get a for loop to start again at any point within the loop? Say line has a length of three. If the if statement is satisfied and my index increments, I want everything to start checking again at the first value of line. 
(Note this whole thing is part of a while True loop).

```
for line in library:
        if message[index:index + len(line)-2] == line[2:]:
            ans += line[0]
            index += len(line)-2 + 1
```

Comment: I don't get what you are asking here ...

Comment: @Arman so line contains values that I want to check substring by substring in message. Currently, when I find a match and increment the index to see if the next bit also has a match in line, it only starts at the next element of line (and skips over the first bits). So even if there is a match, I won't get it. I wondered if I could restart the for loop to the first element of line after index increments?

Comment: there are many ways to do this, have a look into these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492860/python-restarting-a-loop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704918/python-way-to-restart-a-for-loop-similar-to-continue-for-while-loops

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another `while True` above the `for loop`.
For example, this is a continuous loop unless there is a break condition

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
restart = True
while restart:
    for i in x:
        # add any exit condition!
        # if foo == bar:
        #   restart = False
        #   break
        if i == value:  # add your message condition
           break
```

You could replace `x` with `library` in your case and `i` with `line`. Then instead if `i == 4` you add your break condition that resets the loop and if you do have an actual break condition, you set the `restart` flag to `False`

Another option would be using a loop counter like `n = 2` and use `while n < 2:` and then set `n += 1` whenever your condition mets or `n = 0` whenever you want to reset.

Comment: you need an StopIteration catch otherwise it will restart once the list is ended as well

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it right you want to entirely restart the loop when you find a match. Easiest way to do this is by breaking out of the for loop as you stated you have a while loop above it which remains True and will restart the for loop:

```
for line in library:
        if message[index:index + len(line)-2] == line[2:]:
            ans += line[0]
            index += len(line)-2 + 1
            break
```

Comment: How would I break out completely? Yes I have a while loop around all of this, but I have more code beneath this that I want to be able to reach. When I break now I just leave the for loop, but the break brings me back into the for. How do I leave the for and the while to get to the next bits of code? Thanks :)

Comment: update: I got it :) made a string equal to a word and then checked if the word equaled that to break out of it. thanks everyone! xx

Comment: @K.Carpenter Good to hear! Although, if you simply want to exit the while loop when you have reached the end of the for loop(including restarts) you could just add an else statement on the same indentation as the for loop in which you turn the while loop condition to False. This else statement will be reached when the for loop ends.