# restarting for cycle iterating over list python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

[python] 3.6
Hello, I was trying to iterate over a list with a for cycle, where I had to restart the cycle whenever a condition was confirmed.
In C I would do:
`for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(list[i] == something)
        i = 0;
 }`

Here I was trying to do this:

```
for x in listPrimes:
    if((num % x) == 0):
        num /= x # divide by the prime
        factorials.append(x)
        x = 2 # reset to the first prime in the list?
```

which doesn't work correctly. What are the ways to reset the for to a certain iteration of the list? Do I have to do the for in some other way?
Thanks for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: restarting a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492860/python-restarting-a-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a while loop:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print("do something", i)
    if random.random() < 0.2:
        print("reset")
        i = -1
    i += 1
```

Specific to your example:

```
i = 0
while i < len(listPrimes):
    x = listPrimes[i]
    if num % x == 0:
        num /= x
        factorials.append(x)
        i = -1
    i += 1
```

Comment: Good answer, just had to change i = 0 inside the if to i = -1, or a continue because i will be incremented after. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop similarly to your C code.

`while i < 10:
    if list[i] == something:
        i = 0
    i += 1`

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.takewhile` util

Here is a contrived example:

```
import itertools

li = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(1, 6):
        print(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x!=i, li)))
        print("new cycle")
```

Output:

```
[]
new cycle
[1]
new cycle
[1, 2]
new cycle
[1, 2, 3]
new cycle
[1, 2, 3, 4]
new cycle
```

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is the most elegant solution. Just for completeness you could wrap your *list* into custom *generator* and let this new *iterable* receive signal to reset the loop.

```
import time

def resetable_generator(li):
    while True:
        for item in li:
            reset = yield item
            if reset:
                break
        else:
            raise StopIteration


x = range(10)
sum = 0
r = resetable_generator(x)
for item in r:
    time.sleep(1)
    sum += item
    if item == 6:
        sum += r.send(True)
    print(sum)
```