# How to reset the index number of for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

```
for x in range(len(pallets_data_list)):
    """
    SOME CODE
    """
    if pallets_data_list[x]['data_id'] == 32:
        # Go back and search again in for loop
```

In above code, I have a `for` loop which is iterating over `pallets_data_list`. Inside this `for` loop, if the condition becomes `True`, I need to go back to `for` loop and start iterating again from 0. Lets consider that the condition becomes `True` at `x = 20`.

To reset `x`, I am setting it to `0` and then using `continue` like below:

```
    if pallets_data_list[x]['data_id'] == 32:
        # Go back and search again in for loop
        x = 0
        continue
```

Using `continue`, its going back to `for` loop but `x` is not reset and starts iterating from `21`. Is there any way, I can reset `x` again back to `0`. Can anyone please suggest any good solution. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: restarting a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492860/python-restarting-a-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful not to create an infinite loop by resetting the index. You can use a `while` loop with a `found` flag to avoid that:

```
pallets_data_list = [1, 4, 6, 32, 23, 14]

x = 0
found = False
while x < len(pallets_data_list):
    print(pallets_data_list[x])
    if not found and pallets_data_list[x] == 32:
        found = True
        x = 0
        continue
    x += 1
```

Output:

```
1
4
6
32
1
4
6
32
23
14
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply do not use a `for` loop but a `while` loop.

The following `for` loop (which does not work):

```
for i in range(n):
    ...
    if condition:
        i = 0
```

should be replaced by:

```
i = 0
while i < n:
    ...
    if condition:
        i = 0
    else:  # normal looping
        i += 1
```

or, with `continue`:

```
i = 0
while i < n:
    ...
    if condition:
        i = 0
        continue
    i += 1
```

---

When using `while` beware of possible infinite looping.
Possible strategies to avoid infinite looping include using a flag or including an extra counter that limits the maximum number of iterations regardless of the logic implemented in the body.

Comment: and what is `n` here in while loop

Comment: @SAndrew Sorry I thought it was clear from the "equivalent except not working `for` loop". `n` is the argument of `range()` in the `for` loop code, i.e. the number of times the loop would execute should the `condition` never be `True`.